# Months difference between dates

Tags: .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference in months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525990/difference-in-months)

Hi all:

how can We calculate the months difference between two dates using LINQ ? I can find days difference using:

(p.Account.StateChangeDate.Date - DateTime.Now.Date).Days < 4

but there is no option for months.

Please suggest.

Comment: This has nothing to do with LINQ, it is simply about calculating a date interval in months (as per the dupe).

Comment: In your case, how long is a month, 28, 29, 30 or 31 days? OR are you expecting a whole number of months and a number of days, in which case what happens when going from the 15th of Feb to the 17th April, is it 1 month and 30 days? or 2 months and 2 days?

Comment: I need generic function to calculate the difference of months between two dats and use it in LINQ query

Comment: Check this out for the 100% accurate definition (and code to calculate) .Months - it's not in LINQ but you can convert to it easy. The .NET frameworks ignorance of this issue is fixable with this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916358/a-real-timespan-object-with-years-months

Answer (score 2):

Try [calculating the difference in months between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525990/difference-in-months)

---

Pick the algorithm you want to use from that question.

Then, if you are using Linq2Sql, then almost all of those will get mapped back to the database as `DATEPART` type operations (I think).

Alternatively you could do the calc in SQL using a function like in http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/calculating-month-difference.aspx - and could then expose that to Linq2Sql as a function

Answer (score 0):

This should calculate the months for you but it is irregular because some months have 30 days and february, for example, can have 28 or 29.

```
int months = MaxDate.Subtract(MinDate).Days / 30;
```