# Linq static method error

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have created following function to get dates difference:

```
    public static double MonthsDifference(DateTime dtStart, DateTime dtNow)
    {
        DateTime start = dtStart;
        DateTime end = dtNow;
        int compMonth = (end.Month + end.Year * 12) - (start.Month + start.Year * 12);
        double daysInEndMonth = (end - end.AddMonths(1)).Days;
        double months = compMonth + (start.Day - end.Day) / daysInEndMonth;
        return months;
    }
```

I am using it in my LINQ query

```
var query = from c in context.AccountOwners.Where( MonthsDifference(p.Account.StateChangeDate,DateTime.Now) < 4 )
                        select c;
            return query.Count();
```

but it is giving error:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double MonthsDifference(System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Please suggest solution

Comment: firstly. you can create and use functions in a linq to entities call.  however, from my findings it only works if the method is declared in the same class you are trying to use it.

Comment: second.  use the built in entity functions for date/time functions.

Answer (score 1):

The `MonthsDifference` function cannot be mapped to SQL, which is why you are getting this error. You need to either rewrite the query expression *without any calls to your own methods* to do what you want (which may be impossible -- I don't know exactly which native database functions LINQ to Sql supports), *or* fetch the result set and do the filtering locally.

The latter approach would go like this:

```
var count = context.AccountOwners.ToArray()
       .Count(o => MonthsDifference(p.Account.StateChangeDate,DateTime.Now) < 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in the Linq then you need to inline this method so that Linq2Sql can translate it into sql.

So I think you'll need something like:

```
var start = DateTime.Now;
var query = from c in context.AccountOwners
            let accountDate = c.Account.StateChangeDate
            let diff = (start.Month + start.Year * 12) - (accountDate.Month + accountDate.Year * 12) + ...
            where diff < 4
            select c;

return query.Count();
```

---

Linked to [Months difference between dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516015/months-difference-between-dates)

Answer (score 1):

In LINQ to Entities you can use [Entity functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx):

```
using System.Data.Objects;

var query = from c in context.AccountOwners.Where(EntityFunctions.DiffMonths(
                           p.Account.StateChangeDate,DateTime.Now) < 4 )
            select c;
return query.Count();
```