# Create array of months between two dates

Tags: c#, datetime, range

I have the following snippet that I use to get the individual dates between two dates:

```
DateTime[] output = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + endDate.Subtract(startDate).Days)
    .Select(offset => startDate.AddDays(offset))
    .ToArray();
```

However, the following section

```
endDate.Subtract(startDate).Days
```

does not have a .Months to return the months in the date range.

For example, if I provide 1/1/2010 and 6/1/2010 I would expect to return 1/1/2010, 2/1/2010, 3/1/2010, 4/1/2010, 5/1/2010 and 6/1/2010.

Any ideas?

Comment: How would a `Months` property work?   How would it know which Month's # of days to use?  After subtraction you're just left with a TimeSpan which is date-neutral and thus knows nothing about which months to use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference in months](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525990/difference-in-months)

Comment: `.Days` returns the **number of days** in the interval, not the actual days. How do you define the fact that "*a month is between 2 dates*"? The month has **at least 1 day** in that interval? The month has **all days** in the interval? Also how do you need to represent a month using a `DateTime` struct? - as the 1st of the month?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

```
static IEnumerable<DateTime> monthsBetween(DateTime d0, DateTime d1)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, (d1.Year - d0.Year) * 12 + (d1.Month - d0.Month + 1))
                     .Select(m => new DateTime(d0.Year, d0.Month, 1).AddMonths(m));
}
```

This includes both the starting month and the ending month. This finds how many months there is, and then creates a new `DateTime` based on `d0`´s year and month. That means the months are like `yyyy-MM-01`. If you want it to includes the time and day of `d0` you can replace `new DateTime(d0.Year, d0.Month, 1).AddMonths(m)` by `d0.AddMonths(m)`.

I see you need an array, in that case you just use `monthsBetween(..., ...).ToArray()` or put `.ToArray()` inside the method.

Comment: And if you want to get not months, but years, you can do it like this 
Enumerable.Range(0, (d1.Year - d0.Year) + 1)
    .Select(m => new DateTime(d0.Year, 1, 1).AddYears(m))

Answer (score 4):

Since I just needed the year and month in between two dates I modified Lasse Espeholt answer a little. suppose: 
d0 = 2012-11-03

d1 = 2013-02-05

The result will be something like this:

2012-11

2012-12

2013-01

2013-02

```
 private List<Tuple<int,int>> year_month_Between(DateTime d0, DateTime d1)
    {
        List<DateTime> datemonth= Enumerable.Range(0, (d1.Year - d0.Year) * 12 + (d1.Month - d0.Month + 1))
                         .Select(m => new DateTime(d0.Year, d0.Month, 1).AddMonths(m)).ToList();
     List<Tuple<int, int>> yearmonth= new List<Tuple<int,int>>();

        foreach (DateTime x in datemonth)
        {
            yearmonth.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(x.Year, x.Month));
        }
        return yearmonth;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? The requirement is very ambiguous.

```
DateTime[] calendarMonthBoundaries = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + endDate.Subtract(startDate).Days)
    .Select(offset => startDate.AddDays(offset))
    .Where(date => date.Day == 1)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I actually like how simple this solution is! Just analyze all dates between start date and end date, but return only start month dates. Probably not the quickest solution but pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You could enumerate increments of months with:

```
private static IEnumerable<DateTime> ByMonths(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
  DateTime cur = startDate;

  for(int i = 0; cur <= endDate; cur = startDate.AddMonths(++i))
  {
    yield return cur;
  }
}
```

and then call `ToArray()` on that if you want an array. It's reasonably good about having values that are likely to be what is wanted; e.g. if you start at Jan 31<sup>st</sup> you'll next get Feb 28<sup>th</sup> (or 29<sup>th</sup> on leap years), then Mar 31<sup>st</sup>, then Apr 30<sup>th</sup> and so on.

Comment: DateTime[] months = ByMonths({30/01/2013 12:00:00 AM}, {4/04/2013 12:00:00 AM}).ToArray();
This only returns 3 months (jan, feb, mar), April is missing.

Comment: @DaveLucre I'm not sure that's a bad thing, because I'm not sure just what the requirement in the question is considering "between". It could certainly be amended to include April in that case, I just don't know if it should.