# EF4 using Linq How can i find the date difference in days

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I need to check a difference between a **given date** and **current date** is less than 365days?

i tried some thing like this.

```
System.TimeSpan diff = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract((DateTime)customer.LastValidationDate);
 result = (diff.Days < 1);
```

this doesn't seem to work correct for few dates.

i need to achieve:
if given date and current date difference is less-than or equal to 1 year (365 days) return true
else return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this found at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525990/difference-in-months)

```
    public static int MonthDifference(this DateTime lValue, DateTime rValue)
{
    return (lValue.Month - rValue.Month) + 12 * (lValue.Year - rValue.Year);
}
```