# Get all months names between two given dates

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a function which gives all month name between two dates in c#

```
List<string> liMonths = MyFunction(date1,date2);
```

my function is

```
MyFunction(DateTime date1,DateTime date2)
{

//some code
return listOfMonths;
}
```

can you help me how could i do this

Comment: Got any ideas on how to implement it?

Comment: Should the names of the months of `date1` and `date2` be included in the result?

Comment: @Suhan the OP is asking for the names, not the number of months

Comment: [Please see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930565/list-the-months-between-two-dates)

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827148/easy-way-to-loop-over-months-and-years-from-a-given-date

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No linq-solution yet?

```
var start = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
var end = new DateTime(2013, 6, 22);

// set end-date to end of month
end = new DateTime(end.Year, end.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(end.Year, end.Month));

var diff = Enumerable.Range(0, Int32.MaxValue)
                     .Select(e => start.AddMonths(e))
                     .TakeWhile(e => e <= end)
                     .Select(e => e.ToString("MMMM"));
```

Comment: This is a better solution than the "This question already has an answer here:".

Answer (score 6):

You can use Linq with a helper function

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDates(DateTime date1, DateTime date2) 
{
    while (date1 <= date2) 
    {
        yield return date1;
        date1 = date1.AddMonths(1);
    }

    if (date1 > date2) 
    { 
        // Include the last month
        yield return date1;
    }
}
```

Then MyFunction can be one of the following

1) Include year name

```
List<string> MyFunction(DateTime date1, DateTime date2) {
    return GetDates(date1,date2).Select(x => x.ToString("MMMM yyyyy")).ToList();
}
```

2) Just the month name, with duplicates

```
List<string> MyFunction(DateTime date1, DateTime date2) {
  return GetDates(date1,date2).Select(x => x.ToString("MMMM")).ToList();
}
```

3) Distinct month names

```
List<string> MyFunction(DateTime date1, DateTime date2) {
    return GetDates(date1,date2).Select(x => x.ToString("MMMM")).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Create a loop starts date1 until date2. Add one month for every step of your loop and fill in your return variable the month.

I try to write in meta language your aim:

```
DateTime currDate = date1
List myList = new List();
while (currDate < date2) {
    myList.add(getMonthName(currDate));
    currDate = currDate.addMonth(1);
}
```

Comment: I used you code and realized that `addMonth(1)` doesn't change the value of currDate, you will have to assign `currDate.addMonth(1)` to a new variable and reassign that variable to `currDate` so as to change its value. Simply do this `while (currDate < date2)
            {
                mylist.Add(getMonthName(currDate));
                var newDate = currDate.AddMonths(1);
                currDate= newDate;
            }`

Comment: Hi, I've fixed my answer. with currDate = currDate.addMonth(1);

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime from;
DateTime to;


var source = from.Month > to.Month ?
               Enumerable.Range(from, 12).Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, to.Month))
             : Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
               .SkipWhile(m => m >= from.Month)
               .TakeWhile(m => m <= to.Month)
var monthes = source
     .Select(m => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(m));
```

Comment: Its nice, but think it will fail if your after November to May.

Comment: @Sayse: yes, sure. updated.

Comment: It also fails when your after April 2013 - April 2014, but this may be out of scope of question :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<string> MonthNames(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
    {
        var monthList = new List<string>();

        while (date1 < date2)
        {
            monthList.Add(date1.ToString("MMMM/yyyy"));
            date1 = date1.AddMonths(1);
        }

        return monthList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static IEnumerable<DateTime> monthsBetween(DateTime d0, DateTime d1)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, (d1.Year - d0.Year) * 12 + (d1.Month - d0.Month + 1))
                     .Select(m => new DateTime(d0.Year, d0.Month, 1).AddMonths(m));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private static List<string> MyFunction(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
        {

            var listOfMonths=new List<string>();
            if (date1.CompareTo(date2) == 1)
            {
                var temp = date2;
                date2 = date1;
                date1 = temp;
            }

            var mosSt = date1.Month;
            var mosEn = date2.Month;
            var yearSt = date1.Year;
            var yearEn = date2.Year;

            while (mosSt < mosEn || yearSt < yearEn)
            {
                var temp = new DateTime(yearSt, mosSt, 1);
                listOfMonths.Add(temp.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                mosSt++;
                if (mosSt < 13) continue;
                yearSt++;
                mosSt = 1;
            }

            return listOfMonths;
        }
```