# Pandas loop over custom dates (month year) to (month year+N) for plotting

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, matplotlib

I've been analysing data that runs over several months, and then generating and saving a figure per month. So far, this has worked great when these are within the same calendar year, but I'm stumped as to how to indicate the loop to work when the data crosses over to the next year.

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime
import matplotlib as plt

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df.index = df.Datetime

for month in range(4,12): #Data starts in April in this example
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=1, sharex=True, figsize =(18,10))
    startDate = datetime.date(2016,month,1)
    stopDate = datetime.date(2016,month+1,1)
    date_val = startDate.strftime("%B %Y")

    k=0
    df.PRe[startDate:stopDate].plot(ax=axes[k])
    #ylim, xlim, title etc
    k=1
    df.PRp[startDate:stopDate].plot(ax=axes[k])

    plt.savefig("PRe and PRp in %s.png"%date_val,bbox_inches="tight")
```

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827148/easy-way-to-loop-over-months-and-years-from-a-given-date) gets close, although they use a pandas datetime object instead of the datetime.date object that I've used. Should I modify my code to accommodate the solution, if so, how?
Otherwise, is there a pandas/pythonic way to get this to work once we get beyond 2016 - either for known start and end dates, or better yet, for any start and end date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`dateoffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects):

```
month = 4
startDate = datetime.date(2016,month,1)
print (startDate)
stopDate = (startDate + pd.offsets.MonthBegin()).date()
print (stopDate)
2016-04-01
2016-05-01
```

---

```
month = 4
startDate = datetime.date(2016,month,1)
print (startDate)
stopDate = (startDate + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=1)).date()
print (stopDate)
2016-04-01
2016-05-01
```

Another solution is [datetimeindex partial string indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex-partial-string-indexing) if need select by `year` and `month`:

```
df.PRe['2016-4'].plot(ax=axes[k])
```

---

```
df.PRe[str(2016)+'-'+str(month)].plot(ax=axes[k])
```

Solution if need loop in `datetimeindex` by unique year and month by unique `month` period by [`DatetimeIndex.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html):

```
start = pd.to_datetime('2015-10-24')
rng = pd.date_range(start, periods=10, freq='3W')

df = pd.DataFrame({'PRe': np.random.randint(10, size=10)}, index=rng)  
print (df)
            PRe
2015-10-25    2
2015-11-15    3
2015-12-06    3
2015-12-27    1
2016-01-17    8
2016-02-07    4
2016-02-28    2
2016-03-20    6
2016-04-10    8
2016-05-01    0
2015-10-25    2
```

```
for date in df.index.to_period('m').unique():
    print (df.PRe[str(date)])

Freq: 3W-SUN, Name: PRe, dtype: int32
2015-11-15    3
Freq: 3W-SUN, Name: PRe, dtype: int32
2015-12-06    3
2015-12-27    1
Freq: 3W-SUN, Name: PRe, dtype: int32
2016-01-17    8
Freq: 3W-SUN, Name: PRe, dtype: int32
2016-02-07    4
2016-02-28    2
Freq: 3W-SUN, Name: PRe, dtype: int32
2016-03-20    6
Freq: 3W-SUN, Name: PRe, dtype: int32
2016-04-10    8
Freq: 3W-SUN, Name: PRe, dtype: int32
2016-05-01    0
Freq: 3W-SUN, Name: PRe, dtype: int32
```

Comment: May I know if the `DatetimeIndex.to_period`(`DatetimeIndex.to_pydatetime`) function is applicable to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60692929/filter-by-conditions-and-plot-bulk-graphs-in-python)? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

@jezrael's answer solved the question; below is the solution for posterity.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df.index = df.Datetime

startDate = df.index[0] #seed the while loop, format Timestamp
while (startDate >= df.index[0]) & (startDate < df.index[-1]): 
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=1, sharex=True, figsize =(18,10))

    stopDate = (startDate + pd.offsets.MonthBegin())#stopDate also Timestamp
    date_val = startDate.strftime("%B %Y")#Date as Month Year string

    k=0
    df.PRe[startDate:stopDate].plot(ax=axes[k])
    #ylim, xlim, title etc
    k=1
    df.PRp[startDate:stopDate].plot(ax=axes[k])
    #ylim, xlim, title etc
    plt.savefig("PRe and PRp in %s.png"%date_val,bbox_inches="tight")
    startDate = stopDate
```