# How to calculate list of months in specified date range in UmAlQuraCalendar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umalquracalendar

I want to calculate a list of months in specified date range.

For instance:

```
DateTime StartDate = 24 - 11 - 2014;
DateTime EndDate = 24 - 11 - 2016;
```

I want to calculate all the months between starting and ending date with names of months.

Comment: show what did you try?

Comment: i have tried UmAlQuraCalendar's methods like GetMonthsInYear but it doesn't help as it only give the months of specified year or era.

Comment: and you need to generate list of month with a year? right?

Comment: i need to generate a list of months between specified range of dates.

Comment: i mean, in your example you have 2 years so in your list should be 2 septembers or only 1?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go a static function that do what you need:

```
    public static Dictionary<int, string> MonthsBetween(
        DateTime startDate,
        DateTime endDate)
    {
        DateTime iterator;
        DateTime limit;

        if (endDate > startDate)
        {
            iterator = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, 1);
            limit = endDate;
        }
        else
        {
            iterator = new DateTime(endDate.Year, endDate.Month, 1);
            limit = startDate;
        }

        var dateTimeFormat = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
        var result = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        while (iterator <= limit)
        {
            if (!result.Keys.Contains(iterator.Month))
                result.Add(iterator.Month, dateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(iterator.Month));
            iterator = iterator.AddMonths(1);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

you can use it like this:

```
        DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2014, 11, 24);
        DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2016, 11, 24);

        var list = Program.MonthsBetween(startDate, endDate);
```

`list` variable contains dictionary with month int value and name according to `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` of your program.

I get this function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11930768/1849444) and slightly modify it.