# Calling Get Months between 2 dates C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to call the `GetMonths()` method during the `Row_Inserting()` method but it shows me an error. Also, how do I copy the value of this method to a variable named `Total_Pay`?

```
public override bool Row_Inserting(OrderedDictionary rsold, ref OrderedDictionary rsnew) 
{      
    GetMonths(FROM_DATE, TO_DATE);
    return true;
}

public int GetMonths(DateTime FROM_DATE, DateTime TO_DATE)
{
    if (FROM_DATE > TO_DATE)
    {
        throw new Exception("Start Date is greater than the End Date");
    }

    int months = ((TO_DATE.Year * 12) + TO_DATE.Month) - ((FROM_DATE.Year * 12) + FROM_DATE.Month);

    if (TO_DATE.Day >= FROM_DATE.Day)
    {
        months++;
    }

    return months;
}
```

Comment: And what is wrong with this code? Please explain more.

Comment: the calling GetMonths(FROM_DATE, TO_DATE); is wrong way to call this method

Comment: Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

 Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'ASP._Page_UNPAID_LEAVESadd_cshtml.cUNPAID_LEAVES_add<C,S>.GetMonths(System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' has some invalid arguments

Source Error:


 


Line 27:             GetMonths(FROM_DATE, TO_DATE);

Comment: Could you please post declaration of FROM_DATE and TO_DATE?

Comment: these come from database with datetime datatype

Comment: Do you need to cast them?

Comment: As @KamilStachowiak has said, can we please see your declaration of the variables `FROM_DATE` and `TO_DATE` in your code? Could we also see where and how they are being set?

Comment: The two parameters in this line: `GetMonths(FROM_DATE, TO_DATE);` is *definitely not* of type `DateTime` or the compiler would've allowed the call. Show us the definition of those two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps..

```
    public override bool Row_Inserting(OrderedDictionary rsold, ref OrderedDictionary rsnew)
    {
        int Total_Pay;
        DateTime FROM_DATE = DateTime.Parse("02-May-2016"); //Replace with date you need
        DateTime TO_DATE = DateTime.Parse("08-May-2016"); //Replace with date you need
        Total_Pay = GetMonths(FROM_DATE, TO_DATE);
        return true;
    }

    public int GetMonths(DateTime FROM_DATE, DateTime TO_DATE)
    {
        if (FROM_DATE > TO_DATE)
        {
            throw new Exception("Start Date is greater than the End Date");
        }
        int months = ((TO_DATE.Year * 12) + TO_DATE.Month) - ((FROM_DATE.Year * 12) + FROM_DATE.Month);
        if (TO_DATE.Day >= FROM_DATE.Day)
        {
            months++;
        }
        return months;
    }
```

And checkout this similar question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930565/list-the-months-between-two-dates?rq=1)

Comment: A simple DateTime subtraction yields a TimeSpan, thus you'll have a straightforward way to get the months. Isn't that simpler?

Comment: Yes, but it's difficult to calculate the month with 31 days and the February of leap year etc. On second though ill explain ;), datetime subtraction

Comment: On second though ill explain ;), DateTime subtraction give you difference in date you will need to calculate number of months by hand. The obvious choice is / 30 and for a count down purpose it's fine. but, when showing as difference between 2 dates we need to be more accurate.

Comment: TimeSpan unfortunately does not implement Months or TotalMonths

Comment: Gotcha! I didn't check for the months property.