# C#: How to write expression to findout age from date of birth in report viewer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer

I have date of birth stored in mysql database in string format of Like "02 December, 2014". I Have to calculate Age from this string in report viewer C#? How to write expression.?

Comment: What is your effort so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static string FindAge(string DateOfBirth)
    {
        DateTime Birthdate = new DateTime();
        DateTime.TryParse(DateOfBirth, out Birthdate);
        TimeSpan TempAge = DateTime.Now - Birthdate;
        int Years = (int)TempAge.TotalDays / 365;
        return Years.ToString();

    }
```

Here is a crude example to find years. You'll need to do the formatting you want. If you want the format in years/months/days, it becomes harder because month is a variable unit of measure (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525990/calculating-the-difference-in-months-between-two-dates)). Be more specific as to the format and solutions you've tried yourself so far (as Tzu said). This should help as a starting point though. :)