# How to increment an integer for each passing month after a fixed date?

Tags: c#

The need is to keep track of the current season (as an integer) of a game, that increments by one at every 1st of a month.

How is it possible at runtime to count the amount of times it has been the 1st in a month since a fixed date?

Example: Fixed date for season 1 start is `01/04/2015`. A user uses the application at `09/09/15`. At this point the application needs to know, that the current season now is season `6`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is equivalent to computing the difference in months, since then the current day is not counted. So this answer here will apply to your specific problem as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1526004/2606322

```
int months = (now.Month - start.Month) + 12 * (now.Year - start.Year);
```

There is a subtile difference however. If your start date is on a 1st, you have to add another month, whether or not you want to count that.

```
int months = (now.Month - start.Month) + 12 * (now.Year - start.Year) + (start.Day == 1 ? 1 : 0);
```

Or, if you want to have a 1 based count, just add 1, as you probably do in your example.

```
int months = (now.Month - start.Month) + 12 * (now.Year - start.Year) + 1;
```

Comment: If that link contains the answer, why not vote to close the question as a duplicate instead of reposting?

Comment: The question is different, since he wants the number of times the 1st has passed, as opposed to the difference in months. The answer is the same, but I feel there is a significant semantic difference.

Comment: @DavidG: Pointed out the difference now. Hope that is fine with you. There *is* a difference of +/-1 depending on how you define it. Just wanted to give credit to a similar algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand the question correctly

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2014, 4, 1);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
// since you have taken the "1" start is 01/04/2015.
int Diff = (dt2.Month - dt1.Month) + ((dt2.Year - dt1.Year) * 12) + 1;
```

Comment: There's really no need to post a screenshot of the code running, it brings nothing extra to the answer.

Comment: @DavidG It show the the value of Diff is `6`

Comment: That could be mentioned in text, the image adds nothing of value.

Comment: Anyway your code doesn't work. Change the first date to be in `1-April-2014` and it will still return 6.

Comment: @DavidG Thats why I have uploaded the image as well. :P

Comment: Let me say again: Your code does *not* work.