# How to check if a datetime is exactly a month before today´s date in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm making a program for project control, and I´d like it to validate the start date using the condition that it has to be atleast a month before today. I pretty much have no idea what im doing when it comes to datetime so any help would be appreciated. And before you ask, no it´s not homework, I'm teaching myself c#.

Comment: What does "exactly a month" mean to you?

Comment: Have you read the `DateTime` documentation?

Comment: a month, like if today is 18, I´d like the start date to be at least a month before today, 18 october for example.

Comment: Where can i find the documentation.

Comment: Look at the answer from Jon Skeet here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525990/calculating-the-difference-in-months-between-two-dates

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 (DateTime on MSDN) Documentation on DateTime

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this `date == DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);`?

Comment: Just to clarify, this will only match if `date` is also truncated to the `.Today` part, if it includes a legitimate time part, this check will fail.

Comment: @RonBeyer "Truncate" is misleading. You can't truncate time in .NET. You can only set it to a specific time--midnight in this case. (Nit-picky, I know.)

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date
DateTime oneMonthAgo = today.AddMonth(-1);
bool isOk = startDate <= oneMonthAgo; // or < ? define exact condition for your requirement
```

DateTime class has plenty of useful method to deal with Date in many way: use them!