# How to get months difference between two dates using datediff in c#

Tags: datediff

I have two date fields where i need to caluculate difference in months between those two dates how can i do this.Below is my formula

```
(start.Year * 12 + start.Month) - (end.Year * 12 + end.Month);
```

Expected Result

```
Start Date      End Date      Need to get output as
08/28/2019      09/02/2019            1
06/01/2019      09/02/2019            4
01/02/2019      03/02/2019            3
01/02/2019      03/05/2019            3
```

Comment: Your title says you want to do this in C#, yet you've tagged jQuery - so which is it? In either case I'm 100% certain there is an answer to this already

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference in months between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638993/difference-in-months-between-two-dates)

Comment: i had already tried them but i am not getting the expected out put

Comment: from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525990/calculating-the-difference-in-months-between-two-dates): `For example, should dates like July 5, 2009 and August 4, 2009 yield one month or zero months difference? If you say it should yield one, then what about July 31, 2009 and August 1, 2009? Is that a month? Is it simply the difference of the Month values for the dates, or is it more related to an actual span of time?`. This is very much non trivial!

Comment: You should tell us what output you do get. And it should be end-start, not start-end.

Comment: July 5, 2009 and August 4, 2009 1 month, July 31, 2009 and August 1, 2009? also should be one month,but 01/02/2019      03/02/2019 should yield 3 months

Comment: @abc If you edit out the data that we need to help you solve the problem then the question will have to be closed. I rolled back that edit for you.

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't told us what the rule is for calculating the result you're after, it *looks like* you need to check the day-of-month and add one if the end one is the same or later:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        class DatePair
        {
            public DateTime Start { get; set; }
            public DateTime End { get; set; }

            public DatePair(string s)
            {
                var ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                var parts = s.Split(",".ToCharArray());
                this.Start = DateTime.Parse(parts[0], ci);
                this.End = DateTime.Parse(parts[1], ci);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string dats = "08/28/2019,09/02/2019;06/01/2019,09/02/2019;01/02/2019,03/02/2019;01/02/2019,03/05/2019";
            var dates = dats.Split(";".ToCharArray()).Select(p => new DatePair(p));

            foreach (DatePair d in dates)
            {
                var x = d.End.Month - d.Start.Month;
                if (d.End.Day >= d.Start.Day) { x += 1; }
                Console.WriteLine(d.Start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " " + d.End.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " " + x.ToString());

            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

> 2019-08-28 2019-09-02 1
>   2019-06-01 2019-09-02 4
>   2019-01-02 2019-03-02 3
>   2019-01-02 2019-03-05 3

I did not include the years in the calculation as there was no example date for that.